# Add an ' at the beggining of each line and remove the comma on the last line

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```js
function addComma() {
  // get textarea's content
  var content = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;

  // replace all newline's with ';\n'
  var replaced = content.replace(/\n/g, '\',\n');

  // rewrite the content with the new content
  document.getElementById('myTextArea').value = replaced;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='myTextArea' rows='5' cols='30'>
    First Line
    Second Line
    Third Line
    </textarea>
<input type='button' onclick='addComma()' value='Add Comma' />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jw7t68f5

How can I add an ' at the beggining of each line BUT remove the comma on the last line. (I will be having more than three rows.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split` and `map`:

```js
function addComma() {
  var content = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
  //Add in commas and speech marks
  var replaced = content.split("\n").map(e => `'${e}',`).join("\n");
  //Remove last comma
  replaced = replaced.substring(0, replaced.length - 1);
  //Put text back into page
  document.getElementById('myTextArea').value = replaced;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='myTextArea' rows='5' cols='30'>
First Line
Second Line
Third Line</textarea>
<input type='button' onclick='addComma()' value='Add Comma' />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't remove the last comma but it adds at the end a new line with speech marks. (without comma)

Comment: That's fixed now - it was the whitespace at the end between `Third Line` and `</textarea>`. Does it suit your needs @JacobK.?

Comment: No problem @JacobK., always glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach that I think get's the result you're looking for:

```
var replaced = content.split('\n').map(l => "'" + l + "'").join(',\n')
```

What this will do is split the content into an array (by the new line), the `map` function will basically loop through each line and add ' at the start and end, finally `join` will join the array back into a string using a comma and new line

Answer (score 1):

My filter makes sure there are no empty lines; No need for substring fiddling around.

```
var replaced = content.split('\n').filter(p=>p!="").map(p=>'\''+p).join(',\n');
```

Comment: LE. Using your code, it doesn't add a speech mark at the end of the line. =/